# How to visit Edinburgh during a layover at Edinburgh Airport?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, edinburgh, edi

Is a 6 hour layover in Edinburgh enough time to get into the city (Apple Store) and back to the airport in time for your next flight? If so, how do you recommend I get to the city and back?

Comment: the apple store is probably not the first thing I would visit if I had a few hours in Edinburgh...

Comment: What kind of itineraries have layovers at Edinburgh Airport?

Comment: @njzk2 +1 for your comment, but you could have given some recommendations of places to visit... (e.g. Scott Monument, Royal Mile, Fudge Kitchen (on the Royal Mile), Edinburgh Castle, Edinburgh University are 2-20 mins. walk from the bus/train stop).

Comment: Do you need to get to the Apple Store specifically or do you want to visit the city ?

Comment: Take a taxi or the 'topless' bus. Skip the generic Apple store. Just find a pub near the airport and have a pint of Guinness. Or two.

Comment: @njzk2 Maybe not, but if your final destination is East Midlands and you have to stay there for two months and just had to return your iPhone to your old employer, then the Apple Store suddenly isn't such a bad pitstop no?

Comment: @MaciejSwic I have no idea what you mean. I don't see the relation between going to the apple store and returning a iPhone to someone.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, but a day in Edinburgh and you'd recommend Guinness?? You can get Guinness in over 120 countries! Have a local pint, like the hand-brewed Caledonian "80/-" or "Deuchars IPA".

Comment: @Earthliŋ: 6 hours, less commute time :-). The goal would be good company, not Guinness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything you need to know is on the airport's [Transport Links](http://www.edinburghairport.com/transport-links). The short answer is yes, easily.

The fastest, but most expensive, way is just to take a taxi. Follow the signs to the taxi rank, should take around 20 to 30 mins to get into town and budget around 25 pounds one way. You can pick up any black cab on the way back.

Trams are 8 pounds return, run every ten minutes or so (officially every 8 to 12 minutes) and go down Princes Street which I'm guessing is the [Apple Store](http://www.apple.com/uk/retail/princesstreet/) you wish to go to. You can get off on the terminus or just after it turns off Princes Street. Journey time is around 35 minutes.

Similarly the Airlink bus is 50p cheaper, takes about as long, runs about as often and stops at Waverly which is a short walk.

There are local buses that are much cheaper, but they take a long route and stop *a lot*, I doubt it's worth it.

So, even if you want to get back to the airport two hours before departure you'd still easily manage two and a half to three hours in the city. Time enough to go shopping and grab a bite to eat.

Of course you'll have to clear security when you return to the airport, and this can take a looong time during peak hours. They've redone the security area so it's faster now but it can get very busy. Also if you're pulled over for further screening you may need to wait in a queue for that. Basically I wouldn't try cutting it too close.

I'm also assuming that you can legally enter the UK.

I guess any big bags will left on the plane but for what it's worth there's a [left luggage](http://www.edinburghairport.com/prepare/services-and-facilities/left-luggage) service at Edinburgh airport. There's also one at [Waverley Station](http://www.left-baggage.co.uk/index/locations) but the airport one is cheaper.

Comment: Ach. You beat me!

Comment: Both answers are excellent, but i have to accept one, and this was first. Sorry @JoErNanO

Answer (score 6):

[The Edinburgh Airport website has a page on Transport Links with details of several options to get you to/from the airport.](http://www.edinburghairport.com/transport-links) The public transport options include Taxis, Buses, Coaches and the Tram. Assuming cost is not an issue, here are indicative journey times into the city centre using the different means of transportation (the Apple store is next to Edinburgh Waverley train station which is right smack in the centre of the city), quoted from the linked airport website:

- Taxi: ~25 minutes
- Buses/Coaches: ~30 minutes
- Tram: ~35 minutes

Being conservative here we can say that you'll need 1h to go through customs and pick up any hold luggage from the retrieval area, and 2h to check-in and drop your luggage on your way out of EDI. Leaving 3h for the return trip to/from the Apple store. The endeavour would therefore seem feasible.

When it comes to the dis/advantages of the different means of transportation, an obvious one is traffic which will inevitably influence your total journey time. This is especially true during peak hours. The tram on the other hand runs on dedicated roads for part of its journey, and therefore the journey time shouldn't be hindered by traffic as much. It is also worthy to note that the route to/from the airport has some bus lanes, which can be used by taxis too, that can help avoid traffic.

Comment: I only beat you by a minute :) But I should note that the tram does not run on dedicated roads for it's entire length and does share the road with traffic. As I understand it has dedicated signals and priorities but really bad traffic can delay it. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edinburgh_Trams): "The tramway uses a mix of street running and segregated off-road track, with conventional tram stop platforms."

Comment: @SpaceDog Good to know. I added this info to the answer. :)